# Place holders in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, placeholder

I have problem with placeholders in Wordpress Onetone theme. When I change text in placehoder tags to my preferred text it works, until I press on that field again and then text resest to it's older text. For example, I change "Email" to word "whatever" , save it, go to website, it shows word "whatever" in input area, and when i press with mouse on that area and then somewhere else, it resets back to "Email". How I could make that my text in placeholder would be permanent?

```
<div class="contact-area">
          <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="">
           <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" size="22" tabindex="1" aria-required="true">
           <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" size="22" tabindex="2" aria-required="true"> 
           <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="39" rows="7" tabindex="4" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
           <p class="noticefailed"></p>
           <input type="hidden" name="sendto" id="sendto" value="tomas@bandymasvienas.esy.es">
           <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Post">
          </form>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. If you want to be text all time same, you need to find your .js file with your desired function and edit text in there and placeholders will show text you want.